# Export a variable from a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

All I want is take `userId` variable's value to use anything.

```
async function getMyData(){
    const token = '';
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);
    
    const data = await spotifyApi.getMe();
    let userId = data.body.id;

    return userId;
}

const userId = getMyData();
console.log(userId)
```

`console.log(userId)` saying me this: `{Promise <pending<}`

Comment: Because I will export getMyData function to another .js file and then i will run getMyData to learn user's spotify id.

Comment: "module.exports = getMyData()" should work

Comment: var getMyData = require('getMyData') ||||||| console.log(getMyData) |||| results: {promise <pending>} (it didnt work too)

Comment: its because the function is async, use await getMyData()

Comment: when i use await getMyData() results are saying: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any `async` functions, don't forget to use `await` before function execution

```
/// ./getMyData.js
export async function getMyData(){
    // ...

    return userId;
}

/// ./otherFile.js

import {getMyData} from './getMyData.js'

(async function () {
   const userId = await getMyData();
   console.log(userId)
})()
```

Comment: This is error when i try your code : (SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules)

Comment: @questiontoansw because you should call this `await getMyData()` also in async scope

Answer (score 2):

you are using async await features in your code.

Thus the return type of your getMyData would actually be a Promise object.
[More about Promises here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)

Now, heres how you can use your function in another file without having to use the `await` keyword.

```
import { getMyData } from '%your file path%';

getMyData().then(function(userId) {
   // use the value of userId here
   console.log(userId);
}
```